# Facebook OG:Video Meta Tag does not actually allow video to be played

Tags: facebook, video, meta-tags

I have according to the Facebook debugger correctly implemented the meta tag OG:video. When someone share's the page the video is posted onto their timeline. However when someone wants to play the video the screen goes white and just out of view it days 'download content'.

I cannot find any documentation on the cause or solution of this. The video is an MP4 roughly 30 seconds in length.

Comment: Do you have a link to the page? You are sure that you have specified secure video url?

Comment: Do you have a testable link? Make a test page so we can check the OG tags & related content are all correct for FB expectations.. Like @WizKid said, video URL must be from **https** server.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I get the white screen with the download link when I set the og:video tag with a facebook video url, and I get a white screen with a .mp4 video from a external source. I also tried with a youtube video url and the youtube video embed url with the same results. I think is a bug on facebook but no idea on how to solve it.

Comment: If some want to check this is the url I'm sharing http://www.sentirsebienescontagioso.com/custom_story_test/action_type/positivismo

Comment: is there a fix for this?